# How to make a javascript that will change words on the site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like this

```
<html>

<body>
<h> Hello everybody, what's up? </h>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Cras ex arcu,consequat sit amet volutpat vitae, finibus vel massa.  
    Sed eleifend quis justo eu auctor.
</p>
    Swap from:<br>
    <input type="text" name="from"><br>
    Swap to:<br>
    <input type="text" name="to"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="DO IT!">
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to add a script that would change the word given by me in the 'Swap from' text box into the another word given by me in the 'Swap to' text box and appear in the Lorem ipsum text.

I know there should be something like:

```
<button onclick="replaceText()">Click me!</button>
```

and some javascript to get the values from 'Swap from' and 'Swap to' but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Well, you'll have to get the **value**s from the `from` box and the `to` box, then **replace** the found `from` value with the `to` value. Try it out and we'll help you with specific issues you're having.

Comment: Look at the jQuery `.text()` method to get and set the text of an element. And the Javascript `.replace()` method on strings to perform replacement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No jQuery, pure JavaScript. Enjoy.

```js
function swap() {
  var first = document.getElementById('from').value;
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  var second = document.getElementById('to').value;

  text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(first, 'g'), second);
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h>Hello everybody, what's up?</h>
  <p id='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ex arcu,consequat sit amet volutpat vitae, finibus vel massa. Sed eleifend quis justo eu auctor.
  </p>
  Swap from:
  <br>
  <input id='from' type="text" name="from">
  <br>Swap to:
  <br>
  <input id='to' type="text" name="to">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="swap()" type="submit" value="DO IT!">Do it!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this function to your code.

```
function replaceText(){
    var text, swapFrom, swapTo, editedText;
    swapFrom = document.getElementsByName("from")[0].value;
    swapTo = document.getElementsByName("to")[0].value;
    editedText = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML.replace(RegExp(swapFrom, "g"),swapTo);
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = editedText;
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing the value of `swapFrom`? `<p>` tag has to be changed, it uses `.text`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I copied one test code instead of the final. My bad. Now it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('button').click(function()
{
   var fromValue = $('input[name=from]').val();
   var toValue = $('input[name=to]').val();
   var newText = $('p').text().replace(fromValue,toValue);
   $('p').text(newText);

});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/18xagg6s/1/

Comment: This user is not usign a jQuery ... and I do not understand why he should pull whole library just for few lines of code... (-1)

Comment: why was the question tagged with jquery in the first place ?

Comment: because starting programmers always look at jquery and they have no idea what is difference between pure JS and jquery and after few years that they find that jQuery is hell...

Comment: @DinoMyte did you look at the question tags? It sais JQuery.

Comment: @Franky238 Look at the question tags.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what are you trying to implement? Here is pure Javascript, no jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/hr28xr6p/

And a snippet:

```js
replaceText.onclick = function replacer () {
  var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
  document.getElementById('to').value = from;
}
```

```html
<h> Hello everybody, what's up? </h>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Cras ex arcu,consequat sit amet volutpat vitae, finibus vel massa.  
    Sed eleifend quis justo eu auctor.
</p>
    Swap from:<br>
    <input type="text" name="from" id="from"><br>
    Swap to:<br>
    <input type="text" name="to" id="to"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="DO IT!" id="replaceText">
```

Comment: Why i've got minus? Is there any bad things in my code? Please, explain

Comment: I  think is because you are not using jQuery and someone think that it is issue... i got it too

Comment: The reason is very dubious

Comment: But i have no another reason